# Got "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" installing java Cookbook

Tags: java, ruby, maven, chef-infra, vagrant

I try to set up a vagrant vm using Chef Solo and Berkshelf. I want to use the [maven](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/java) cookbook. "maven" depends on "java" and "java_ark" (which is included in the "java" cookbook). All of them were created by Opscode.

But everytime I get this error:

```
NoMethodError

-------------

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass




Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/java/recipes/default.rb:21:in `from_file'
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/platform-slayer/recipes/slayer_worker.rb:2:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/java/recipes/default.rb:

 14:  # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 15:  # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 16:  # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 17:  # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 18:  # limitations under the License.
 19:  #
 20:  
 21>> include_recipe "java::#{node['java']['install_flavor']}"
 22:  
 23:  # Purge the deprecated Sun Java packages if remove_deprecated_packages is true
 24:  %w[sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre].each do |pkg|
 25:    package pkg do
 26:      action :purge
 27:      only_if { node['java']['remove_deprecated_packages'] }
 28:    end
 29:  end
 30:
```

Does anyone know this issue?
Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: It seems java is not installed. Can you confirm whether java is installed ? Can you print `java -version`

Comment: Thanks for reply! No, the Java installation is aborting with the error I've posted.

Comment: Which OS ? Can you use other package management tools ? Can you print `roles/base.rb` . You might have to override oracle download terms.

Comment: There is no roles/base.rb
Overriding was already done, but no effect.
I use Xubuntu as host OS and Debian Wheezy as guest OS

Comment: If open-jdk is fine with you, I believe `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` will install java. Can you try again after installing java  externally.

Comment: Of course I can install the package manually. But at my company we need a cookbook which setups the whole vm - it has to be ready to use.

Comment: You added `depends 'java'` to `metadata.rb`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that `node['java']` is evaluating to `nil`.

One possible solution is to define the attribute `node['java']['install_flavor']` either in a cookbook or in your Node definition or a relevant Role definition.

But it looks like a bug in the cookbook, because the documentation says a default should apply to the `install_flavor` attribute.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the real problem.  Try hacking your copy of that recipe to get more information; e.g. add a line before the one that failed to print out what the interpolated string should be.

Comment: Yeah, it was right, because the recipe has to be added as dependency in metadata.rb
Thank you for help! ;)

Comment: @Morphesus I think it would be a good idea to add the 'metadata.rb' solution as an answer and choose that as the accepted answer. It will make this page a lot easier to read... You helped solve this issue for me but I almost overlooked that step.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like a bug. For those having similar issues I suggest just use java::openjdk.